# Would you do anything about a question which was answered in the question?

Tags: discussion

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161397/copy-multiple-items-in-listbox-to-clipboard), and its answer was added to the body of the question later by the OP. 
It is a bit confusing to follow, but the OP found what the issue was and updated the question and added an answer saying to read the comments and the question update.

So arguably all the required information is there, so how would you normally proceed in a question like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since they accepted their own answer, which explicitly states to *look at the comments and edited question for the answer* (I have no idea why they would do this, by the way), I see no problem removing the "answer" from the question, and updating the answer with the real answer.

Granted, since you have less than 2000 rep, you run the risk of having your Suggested Edit rejected (for "clearly conflicting with intent of the author" most likely), <strike>but if I don't get to updating the question and answer here in a minute, I'm sure someone else will</strike> so I went ahead and edited it for you.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it was confusing to find a question like that.

Comment: It happens. People add "[Solved]" or "[Fixed]" to their title, and update the question itself. If I see that happen, I immediately advise them to edit the question back and post their own answer.

Comment: @Jongware - of course it happens, doesn't mean it makes sense